# cheanging class on table row

Tags: jquery, row, paging

I use the function

```
`function xxx(nr) { 
$('#tabelafirm1 tr.bg-dark').removeClass('bg-dark');
$(nr).addClass('bg-dark');
```

}`

It works, but the problem is if there is a pagination. Class is removed ONLY on current page.

Comment: You need to run the functions everytime when the table is refreshed.

Comment: Hmm. This function add class to one row in table (chenging background color). But first I want to remove the class from all other rows, only one row must be in defferent color. My function do it, but only on current page, if I have table with 100 rows, and I am on 4 page the class will be removed only from rows number 41 to 50. I want remove from all 100 rows.

Comment: during switching pagination table is not refreshing.

Comment: What are you using ajax, datatable? How you load data on pagination?

Comment: yes, ajax. pagination is automaticly bootstrap.

Comment: Yes, then you just need to call this function in your ajax success handler. So that way it will remove the class first and then apply it again for your specified row.